# Python Scrapy: finding a text in an "href"

Tags: python-3.x, xpath, scrapy

I am using Python 3 and Scrapy.
This is part of my HTML:

```
<div class="class=a1">
  <span class="a-small">TEXT <a class="a-nm" href="/a/b=data1?ie=UTF8&amp;what-i-want=Nice+Home&amp;the-data=correct&amp;text=ABA+DNA&amp;sort=yes">That's Correct
  </span>
</div>
```

In the `href` there is this text: `what-i-want`. I would like to find the `Nice+Home`, which is anything after `what-i-want=` and before the `&amp;` in the `href`.

I tried this to first extract the `href`:

```
the_href = response.xpath('//a[contains(@href, "what-i-want")]/@href')
```

I expected it to return

```
/a/b=data?ie=UTF8&amp;what-i-want=Nice+Home&amp;the-data=correct&amp;text=ABA+DNA&amp;sort=yes
```

so I then can extract the `Nice+Home` from it, but it doesn't work.

How can I do this?

### update

this is what I see at `the_href` output:

```
[<Selector xpath='//a[contains(@href, "what-i-want")]/@href' data='/a/b=data1?ie=UTF8&t'>, 
<Selector xpath='//a[contains(@href, "what-i-want")]/@href' data='/a/b=data2?ie=UTF8&t'>, 
<Selector xpath='//a[contains(@href, "what-i-want")]/@href' data='/a/b=data3?ie=UTF8&t'>, 
<Selector xpath='//a[contains(@href, "what-i-want")]/@href' data='/a/b=data4?ie=UTF8&t'>]
```

Comment: *...but it doesn't work...* What is exact output? Exception?

Comment: It returns a selector list (SelectorList) with 4 items, but I cannot see the `href` content in any of them.

Comment: Does `response.xpath('//a[contains(@href, "what-i-want")]/@href')` returns desired output?

Comment: No, but now I can see that the text I am looking for is in the_href[0].root, does this make sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`response.xpath('//a[contains(@href, "what-i-want")]')` should return you the list of link nodes. If you want to get list of hyper-reference attributes, try

```
the_href = response.xpath('//a[contains(@href, "what-i-want")]/@href').extract()
```

Then you can extract required values as:

```
for href in the_href:
    print(href.split("what-i-want=")[-1].split("&amp")[0])
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but it does not work. As I am using it in a scrapy when I try to debug it goes in `defer.py`. But when I run it without debug, it doesn't print anything.

Comment: What is the output of `the_href = response.xpath('//a[contains(@href, "what-i-want")]/@href')`?

Comment: I responded to your question by updating my question above, thanks for the help.

Comment: Does calling `extract` method solved the issue? Check updated answer